# Last entry in recursive function

Tags: jquery, recursion

I got a JSON array with nested elements, I am trying to print out a nested unordered list,
it seems to work but only returns the last version.  I assume it is because I am declaring the returnstring inside the recursive function so it is just overwriting it. But how else can you do this?
 If I use a global variable, same issue occurs.  If I try concatenating the string, I can see them all, but multiple times.

```
var tree = [{"menu":"A01","parent":"","desc":"HOME"},{"menu":"A02","parent":"","desc":"PREFERENCES","children":[{"menu":"A03","parent":"A02","desc":"Themes"}]},{"menu":"A04","parent":"","desc":"Configure","children":[{"menu":"A05","parent":"A04","desc":"Forms"},{"menu":"A06","parent":"A04","desc":"Users","children":[{"menu":"A07","parent":"A06","desc":"Groups","children":[{"menu":"A08","parent":"A07","desc":"Exit"},{"menu":"A09","parent":"A07","desc":"Restart VS"}]}]}]}];

var endMenu =getMenu(tree);
var retStr ="";
     function getMenu( nodes ){

    nodes.map(function(nodem){
        var subMenu = "";
        if(typeof nodem.children !="undefined"){             
            nodem.children.some(function(childNode){
                if(childNode.parent == nodem.menu)
                    subMenu='<ul>'+ getMenu(nodem.children) + '</ul>'
            });
        }
        retStr = '<li>'+nodem.desc + subMenu + '</li>' ;
    });
    return retStr;        
}
$('#menu').html('<ul>'+endMenu+ '</ul>');
```

I have http://jsfiddle.net/LqES7/73/ for fiddling with

Answer (score 2):

To add to the string on each iteration, you'd do

```
retStr += '<li>'+nodem.desc + subMenu + '</li>' ;
```

you're overwriting it on each iteration, and end up with just the last one !

Comment: That's how I have the current fiddle but then I get stuff like exit, exit, restart, exit, restart, groups, exit, restart, groups, users

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I did have the += on there, I just left it out in the posted code.
But, it turns out it was because I was using .some in conjuction with the parent matches current item check.  I took those out and just used forEach.

 So if anyone needs a JSON nested array to nested list check out this fiddle

```
function getMenu(nodes){
var retStr ="";
    nodes.forEach(function(nodem){
        var subMenu = "";
        if(typeof nodem.children !="undefined"){         
            nodem.children.forEach(function(childNode){
                if(childNode.parent == nodem.menu)
                    subMenu='<ul>'+ getMenu(nodem.children) + '</ul>'
                    });
        }
        retStr += '<li>'+ nodem.desc + subMenu + '</li>' ;
    });
    return retStr;        
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LqES7/74/